# dvips: How to get correct fonts for eps (encapsulated postscript)?

Tags: fonts, pdf, latex, dvi, eps

I have a 12 year old, large Latex document with eps figures in it. Nowadays, when I try to translate it into pdf, I get the following error message:

```
dvips: Font Courier used in file Pictures/MealyAutomat.eps is not in the mapping file.
```

Any idea how to fix this? Do I just have to install a certain font package?

The figures were created with the 'tgif' program a long time ago. I have just installed the 'tgif' package, and I get:

```
$ tgif
Fatal Error in OpenFont(): Cannot open the Default(Msg)Font '-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1'.
Tgif aborted.
```

Comment: I think you need the package `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Comment: This package is already installed.

Comment: What's strange is that installing the texlive-fonts-extra solves the problem in Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04), but not in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I provided a solution for this question here
 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/409697/latex-dvips-font-problem-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problems with xfig fonts. I have only a 13.04 system here, will check later on a 13.10 at home. TeX (and dvips) mappings for Courier in my system are:

```
(0)asus-romano:~/personal/archivio/Tricks% wajig whichpackage /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier
texlive-fonts-recommended: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/adobe/courier
```

So it seems that the package is `texlive-fonts-recommended`, which you should have.

Have you tried to convert the eps to pdf manually with something like epstopdf (probably it will give the same error as you have)? Can you see the `.eps` files correctly in evince or gs?

Another try could be to install the package `gsfonts-x11` which, in `/etc/X11/fonts/Type1/gsfonts-x11.alias`, has definitions for the two fonts you have errors for (at least this *could* make tgif work --- it does in my 13.04).

Comment: I have installed texlive-fonts-recommended and gsfonts-x11; it does not help with the warnings. epstopdf converts the eps's without any complaint. I see the eps files correctly in evince and gs. I also see them in the final pdf. Everything is ok apart from the warnings. Maybe I should just ignore them...

Comment: tgif still crashes on startup with the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for the error, you "simply" have to install the font Courier (which is of property of IBM).

You can install Microsoft Courier New by following the [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Microsoft_Fonts).

Comment: I followed the instructions, but I still get the  same error messages.

Comment: And isn't it an error in the Ubuntu repository system when, on a freshly installed Ubuntu, a freshly installed program like tgif crashes on the very first startup?

Comment: The problem is that you do not have installed all the packages that the file (not the program) needs.If you had used free fonts when creating it, maybe now there will be no problem at all! :) But you chose to use proprietary fonts, so you have to install them (as long as Microsoft allows you to do it) ;)

Comment: No, no. I have not deliberately chosen to use any proprietary font. The Latex document and the eps figures were created 12 years ago with what was preinstalled on SuSE at that time. So what fonts exactly do I need and where do I get them from? I have about 60 eps figures! And apart from that: Even if I try to change them by editing the source files with tgif, as I wrote above, tgif immediately refuses to work on Ubuntu after installation.

Comment: Courier is [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29) a property of Microsoft.

Comment: @MartinSchröder thanks for pointing that out, I modified the answer :)

Comment: @dadexix86: You still have it wrong: "Because IBM deliberately chose not to seek any copyright, trademark, or design patent protection, the Courier typeface cannot now be trademarked or copyrighted and is completely royalty free."

Comment: This is the License agreement, and the property is of IBM :) http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11fonts/X11fonts-14/font-ibm-type1/font-ibm-type1-1.0.3/COPYRIGHT.IBM