# LaTeX/dvips Font Problem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: fonts, latex

On Ubuntu 13.04, many of my `dvips` calls deliver error messages like,

```
dvips: Font Helvetica used in file <...> is not in the mapping file.
```

All these calls work perfectly fine on Ubuntu 12.10 which I'm using in
parallel on my laptop. `gv` can also display the 'missing' fonts if called
directly, so I guess they are installed correctly and it must be an issue with `dvips` in Ubuntu 13.04

I've installed

```
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-fonts-extra
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This bugged me for ages.  This is my solution that works:

1. Locate the file `dvips35.map`

   ```
   locate dvips35.map
   ```

   In my case it is in

   ```
   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/dvips35.map
   ```
2. Create a new file called `.dvipsrc` in your home directory

   ```
   gedit $HOME/.dvipsrc
   ```
3. And copy and paste the following:

   ```
   p +/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/dvips35.map
   ```
4. Run  `updmap` to update the configuration. Helvetica and Times-Roman should now be available.

If you have root access you can add the line in step 3 at the end of the file

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps
```

and run `sudo updmap-sys`. The above location is 14.04. You can locate your own `config.ps` file using:

```
locate config.ps
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot --- have you tried to install `gsfonts-other`?

```
apt-get install gsfonts-other
```

On the other hand, I often had that warning with no ill effects on my output -- check if this is the case. It happened when the dvips swallowed some ".eps" figure.

(Otherwise, try to add a small example file --- so that people can check).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but that's not it, gsfonts-other is installed, and gv can display the fonts. It is also not just a warning, the symbols are really missing.  E.g. when I use the Symbol font, the characters are in the .eps when I directly look at it with .eps, but not in the final .eps when I feed the very same file into a .tex document and go through dvips.  When I look at the intermediate .dvi with xdvi, the syms are there, but as soon as I dvips them, I get aforementioned error message and the syms are gone in the .ps, so I guess it must be an issue with dvips.

Thoughts much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The "official" dvips home page http://www.radicaleye.com/dvips.html says
that for error messages or core dumps, use option -j0 to work around some
issues with current versions of dvips until it gets fixed someday.  I have
no idea what this option does, but it worked for me to get latex to work
right with imported eps files that have timesroman and helvetica fonts;
these same eps files used to work fine for many years on older versions of
dvips, but now don't work with current versions.  Using the -j0 option,
I still get the error messages, but the output of dvips now comes out
correct with no missing characters or symbols.  So give it a shot.